In which state will your income be taxed?
If you do work in Austin, Texas, as a remote online customer care specialist for the Augusta National Resort (situated in Georgia) do you pay Texas or Georgia income tax?

Is this a trick question? Texas has no income tax.

@MTA I'm aware, the question is if you live in Texas and work for a company remotely in Georgia which places tax rules do you follow?

Okay I have made an edit.

To be honest this is going to depend on the states as well as the type of work in question., Some states don't have income tax, some only tax if you live in the state, others tax you for anything you earn in the state even if you don't live there as long as the income is from there.

@JoeW is it then possible to be double taxed? live in a state where anybody earning money and living there gets taxed and then doing online work for an out-of-state company where the rule is anybody earning money even those not living there gets taxed? (Hope that makes sense)(May require its own question)

Yep, it is depending on the job and the states involved.

@NeilMeyer Yes, it is possible to be double taxed, but adjacent states that have significant numbers of daily commuters who cross state lines for employment often enter into interstate tax compacts. These can give full credit against income taxes owed to one's home state for income taxes paid to the neighboring state. A new question would get a complete answer at Money.SE AKA "Personal Finance & Money Stack Exchange."

@MTA You can write the shortcut [money.se]. This will create a link and automatically show it as the full name of the SE site. E.g. [money.se].

@Barmar Jeepers, gotta love them computers! Thanks for the tip.

@MTA I'm pretty sure all states (with income taxes) unilaterally allow a credit on income taxes paid to another state, so a interstate tax compact is not necessary. With the tax credit, the net tax paid is the maximum of both state's taxes. Texas residents end up with a massive disadvantage because their Georgist taxation shift taxes to property tax, which you can't take a out-of-state income tax credit against, so the employee's net taxation is essentially two states combined.

@user71659 Agreed! I've searched for any state that disallows a resident from offsetting income tax paid to another state, and can't find any. (Some exceptions remain for county and city income taxes.) A vast improvement from the days of the patchwork interstate tax compacts that I learned of 50 years ago working in NYC!

It is worth noting that while this example is pretty straight forward, that the general answer to the headline question is quite complex and often results in multiple states taxing your income.

The Texas state constitution, Article 8, Section 24-a prohibits a Texas income tax, full stop, so your question "Texas or Georgia" can not be answered "Texas" under any circumstance.
There is no state income tax at all from the activity you described. Georgia does tax income earned by nonresidents, but only if the work is physically performed in Georgia.
The website freetaxusa.com explains it succinctly as follows:


If you lived and worked remotely for a Georgia employer from another state and you did not physically work at any time in Georgia, your
employer will not be required to withhold any Georgia income taxes on
your W-2. If they do withhold Georgia taxes, you will likely want to
file a Georgia return to be refunded the tax which was withheld.
If you are a Georgia nonresident, you did not physically work in Georgia, and your employer did not withhold Georgia state taxes, you
probably don't need to file a Georgia return at all unless you
otherwise have a Georgia nonresident filing requirement.


Going directly to Georgia tax statutes, § 48-7-30 (2022):


a. The tax imposed by this chapter shall apply to the entire net income of a taxable nonresident derived from employment, trade, business,
professional, or other activity for financial gain or profit performed
or carried on within this state, including, but not limited to, the
rental of real or personal property located within this state or for
use within this state, the sale, exchange, or other disposition of
tangible or intangible property having a situs in this state, the
receipt of proceeds of any lottery prize awarded by the Georgia
Lottery Corporation, and withdrawals of contributions to a savings
trust account under Article 11 of Chapter 3 of Title 20 which are
required to be included in taxable net income as provided in
subparagraph (b)(10)(C) of Code Section 48-7-27.
b. A taxable nonresident whose income is derived from employment, trade, business, professional, or other activity performed or carried
on within and outside this state shall be taxed only upon the income
derived from carrying on the activity within this state. The amount of
taxable income may be determined by a separate accounting of the
income if the commissioner is satisfied that the separate accounting
reflects correctly the income fairly attributable to this state.
Otherwise, the amount of taxable income shall be determined in the
manner prescribed by this chapter for the allocation and apportionment
of income of corporations engaged in business within and outside this
state.


